# Why numpy is almost 25 times faster than Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm running a benchmark between a custom NN made with numpy vs one made with Keras. The Keras model:

```
class TFModel():
    def __init__(self,input_shape,outputs,hidden_units,**kwargs):
        _input = Input(shape=(input_shape))
        layer = Dense(units = input_shape,activation='relu',use_bias=False)(_input)
        for hu in hidden_units:
            layer = Dense(units = hu,activation='relu',use_bias=False)(layer)
        outputs = [Dense(units=out,activation='sigmoid',use_bias=False)(layer) for out in outputs]
        self.model = Model(inputs = _input,outputs=outputs)
        self.total_weights = self.model.count_params()
        
    def predict(self,x):
        prediction = self.model.predict(x)
        return prediction
```

The numpy model:

```
class NeuralNetwork(ActivationFunctions):
    def __init__(self,layers,seed=None):
        self.layers = {}
        self.total_weights = 0
        self._module_to_use = np.random
        self.seed = seed
        if seed is not None:
            self._module_to_use = self._generate_random_state()
        inputs = layers[:-1]
        outputs = layers[1:]
        
        for ins,outs in zip(inputs,outputs):
            self.total_weights += sum(ins.nodes)*sum(outs.nodes)
            layers = self._generate_wt(ins.nodes,outs.nodes)
            actual_len = len(self.layers)
            for idx,layer in enumerate(layers):
                activation = outs.activation                
                if actual_len not in self.layers:
                    self.layers[actual_len] = {}
                self.layers[actual_len][idx] = {
                    'layer':layer,
                    'activation':activation
                }
        self.layers[actual_len]['type'] = 'output'
    
    def _generate_random_state(self):
        return RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(self.seed)))
    
    def _generate_wt(self,x,y):
        return [self._module_to_use.random(size=(_x,_y)) for _x,_y in product(x,y)]

    def f_forward(self,x):
        # hidden
        output = []
        for layer in self.layers.values():
            is_output = layer.get('type',False)
            for lay in layer.values():
                if lay == 'output':
                    continue
                # print(lay)
                activation = getattr(self,lay['activation'])
                lay = lay['layer']
                z = x.dot(lay)
                z = activation(z)
                if is_output:
                    output.append(z)
            x = z
        return output
```

And the auxiliary classes Layers and ActivationFunctions:

```
class ActivationFunctions():
    def softmax(self,x):
        """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
        e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
        return e_x / e_x.sum()
    
    def relu(self,x):
        return x * (x>0)
    
    def sigmoid(self,x):
        return(1/(1 + np.exp(-x)))

class Layer():
    def __init__(self,nodes,activation):
        if isinstance(nodes,int):
            nodes = (nodes,)
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.activation = activation
```

I'm setting an input on a variable i:

```
i = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(1,24))
```

So, I have disabled eager execution by using `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`. Timing the execution with keras gives the following output (I'm using Jupyter Notebook):

```
input_shape = 24
outputs = [6,2]
hidden_units = [10]

tf_model = TFModel(input_shape,outputs,hidden_units)

%timeit -n 100 -r 10 tf_model.model.predict(i)
>416 µs ± 19.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
```

On the other hand, the execution with numpy gives an output way lower:

```
layers = [(24,24,10,(6,2)),(None,'relu','relu','softmax')]
layers = [Layer(node,act) for node,act in zip(*layers)]
nn =  NeuralNetwork(layers)

%timeit -n 100 -r 10 nn.f_forward(i)
>17 µs ± 4.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Why is this? I am doing something wrong? My TF version is `2.13.0`

Comment: Have you compared both models outputs and made sure they are the same? Chances are, you did something wrong in your NumPy implementation. Implementing a neural network takes knowledge, however implementing one faster than TensorFlow, a well-optimized and widely used deep learning library, is highly improbable.

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example.

Comment: You should not use `model.predict`, this likely has some overhead. Instead call the model directly, i.e. `model(x)`. Also, if you are running on a GPU, the overhead from copying data to/from the GPU may be higher than the performance gain for such a small network. Finally, if you disabled eager execution, make sure the TF model is run at least once _before_ timing it so the graph can be built.

Comment: In addition to @xdurch0's comment, here's what happens under the hood when you use predict: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18062#issuecomment-1530134732